# Url Storage, History & Personal Data

Tags: web-browser, memory, windows-10, url, data-recovery

Just Curious to Know,
Where my information is being stored and how long its kept for
I'm running the latest version of windows 10,
my main Browser being firefox developer edition 68.

I clear my history regularly, as it clogs up memory and is unnecessary
wasted resources. However, I can completely Clear my browsing history, through firefox, delete all history & cookies, saved session etc. Then I also Use CCleaner and BleachBit to clear the rest of the junk on my hard-drive. Although Firefox Say's history is cleared, and it acts like it has!But When I type in a new Search in the address bar it is still auto complete's, address's and searches that I have done prior to the full system Clean. Obviously it is Still storing Url And searches somewhere.Where is that information kept?

I want to know as to where it is being stored and to view how much memory it is actually taking up, as well as how far back it goes? I am Also Clearing Memory and Caches though the generic Windows utility & have also Cleared the Cache Folder called: 'CryptnetUrlCache'. So where is this information being stored? I am unsure if this would be the same for Opera or Explorer but I think its safe to assume that is would be.

Why say **Clearing history**, if it in fact isn't doing so?

Comment: Whilst I can't answer your question directly, I would caution about too aggressive a use of CCleaner if you're not 100% sure of what you're deleting. I've destroyed more than one windows registry in the past :)

Comment: I have made some edits.Changed language a bit,added a few things,removed the things that dont contribute to the question,feel free to edit more